# How can I understand what this error in reactjs is?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, cookies

I have a small project in React and I noticed in the Google Chrome console one error

> Uncaught true

[image: Console Error]

[image: VM1270]

[image: VM1269]

The `throw true` seems to be the uncaught part. What could it be that causes this issue? Should I just ignore it?

Comment: Please share your component code where you're throwing this error?

Comment: Hi Cristian, you should only throw when you are able to catch and based on the code that you have there, I can safely say that you are not catching the throw anywhere.
A couple of things to consider would be:
Why are you using throw there, could you use return instead?
Is it possible to call that code in a try/catch if throw is required?
Could there be an entirely different way to do what you are attempting to do?

Comment: The guy who answered is right. I had Tampermonkey userscript manager and it would just throw this error. I am exhausted that I forgot I installed that. Enough programming for today! Or maybe not xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [User Script](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) installed in your Chrome browser, which I'm guessing is unrelated to your project. When the current URL matches a certain pattern, this particular script runs, checks for a cookie being set and then stops the remainder of the script from running by throwing an error.

To be honest, that script looks like it could potentially be malicious if you don't know what it is and it is not part of your project. If I had something like this, I'd be looking at what those URLs relate to and disabling the userscript if they look suspicious.

Comment: You are so right mate! It was Tampermonkey userscript manager that was throwing this error. I forgot I installed that. You're a genius. Thanks a lot